# Add multiple category search functionality to a website

Tags: html, search, web, categories

I am building the website for a letting agents.

I would like to know the best way to integrate multiple category ( price, location, number of bedrooms ) searches into the site, so that the user can select options / type these in and get results displayed.

If someone could help me with this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is relational database with several columns

```
CREATE TABLE `places` (
  `price_in_cents` int(11),
  `location` varchar(255),
  `num_of_bedrooms` tinyint(2)
)
```

You might also want to consider breaking down location into a separate fields like country, state, city, ...

in this case you can leverage SQL like:

```
select * from places where price_in_cents between 100 and 10000000 and location like '%Francisco%' and bedrooms between 1 and 3;
```